Monitoring validation loss with confident mispredictions
I am working on a binary classification task using a variant of ResNet. The dataset consists of medical recordings and is relatively small (N=2000), though I apply various validated data augmentation techniques to mitigate this limitation. The overall task is to predict treatment responses of each patient, given their medical data (time series).
I use BCE loss in this task. As training progresses, although some subjects in the validation set show improvement (more correct probability predictions), the model’s confident errors on others tend to worsen, causing the overall validation BCE loss to increase. Then, it becomes very hard to determine when to stop training. I suspect that the dataset might contain noisy labels, as some subjects are likely to have been mislabeled or had their treatment changed after the labels were assigned. This might cause some of those confident mistakes.
Given this, what would be the best strategy to monitor training performance across epochs and determine the optimal stopping point?
